# Caffeine cache key expiry

Tags: caffeine-cache

I wanted to check if Caffeine cache keys are refreshed after expiry when they are specifically operated upon (get etc.) or if any operation on the cache itself, i.e. adding new keys, modifying or accessing different keys, etc. can trigger the refresh on the expired keys.

Also, is there a periodic refresh/cleanup of expired keys even if the whole cache is not accessed for a time?

Comment: You can use `Caffeine.scheduler` to enable automatic removal of expired entries when there is no activity. A periodic refresh (e.g. reload keys every 10 minutes) is left to user code since that is straightforward and makes the behavior clearer (e.g. use a ScheduledExecutorService to reload by iterating over the asMap() view)

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to confirm that the key refresh is not triggered by a read or write operation on any other key of the cache or getting stats etc.

Comment: I also had a query on behavior when multiple concurrent calls are made for a key that is getting refreshed. Let's say 5 concurrent calls try to get a key that is past its refresh date, do all 5 calls get returned the stale value and the reload function is triggered or does only the first one get the stale value and the other 4 will wait for the reload call to be completed and will get the updated value?

Comment: A refresh is triggered as a side effect of reading the entry; there is no cross-key influence. It is an optimistic reload so all readers will receive the current value while in-flight; there is no blocking involved. Only one reload will be performed by an atomic transition. If the key is modified (delete or update) then the in-flight refresh will be abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

The below comments from @Ben Manes on the original question have answered my question.
[Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77808940/timeline#comment_137171314)

[Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77808940/timeline#comment_137255079)